# Creating custom icon from an image in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create an icon, that should work like `font-awesome` and whenever I apply a class it shows an image based on font-size. I have been able to do it in chrome, but the same code doesn't work in Firefox.

```css
div {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.custom-icon-jazz {
    content: url(https://image.ibb.co/iHHaWS/jazzcash_color_logo.png);
    height: 2em;
    width: 4em;
  }
  .custom-icon-jazz::before {
    content: url(https://image.ibb.co/iHHaWS/jazzcash_color_logo.png);
    height: 2em;
    width: 4em;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <i class="custom-icon-jazz"></i>  
</div>
```

`::before` works for firefox only. in chrome, the normal class gets applied easily.

Just to make it easy I have created this [pen](https://codepen.io/muhammadfaizan/pen/ddzgrq) which shows the image in different sizes on different browsers, you can see this link and notice the difference between firefox and chrome rendering of this pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the :after pseudo-element is a box, which in turn contains the generated image. There is no way to style the image, but you can style the box. Adjusting the background-size is permitted. You still need to specify width and height of the block, however.

You should try following way:

```css
div {
  font-size: 14px;
  .custom-icon-jazz {
    background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/iHHaWS/jazzcash_color_logo.png);
    background-size: 4em 2em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 4em;
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-icon-jazz::before {
    background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/iHHaWS/jazzcash_color_logo.png);
    background-size: 4em 2em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 4em;
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <i class="custom-icon-jazz"></i>  
</div>
```